# How to fix: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm helping a NGO with their website (http://aapot.com.br) and I'm getting an error on a script that fetches photos from a Facebook album.

It was working fine on Localhost but when I moved to the server, it gives an error.

The script is:

```
<?php
                $json_link = "http://graph.facebook.com/207640916063623/photos?fields=source";
                $json = file_get_contents($json_link);
                $obj = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
                $photo_count = count($obj['data']);
                for($x=0; $x<$photo_count; $x++){
                $source = $obj['data'][$x]['source'];
                $id = $obj['data'][$x]['id'];
                    echo "<li style='width:auto !important;height:100px;'><a href='#{$id}' data-toggle='modal'><img src='{$source}' style='width:auto !important;height:150px;' /></a>";
                    echo "</li>";
                }
            ?>
```

It gets the following error:

Warning: : file_get_contents(http://graph.facebook.com/207640916063623/photos?fields=source): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /home/u295274872/public_html/wp-content/themes/aapot/index.php  on line 40.

I've already checked and fopen is enabled. The PHP version is 5.5.

Please, any ideas about how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the server behind a proxy? Which result do you get with `wget` on linux console (if you have shell access)?

Comment: Hi @hellcode - Sorry, I don't have shell access. It's a shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `urlencode();`

```
<?php
$json_link = urlencode("http://graph.facebook.com/207640916063623/photos?fields=source");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks,@Rina. I forgot to mention it, but I had tried to use curl already with no success.

Comment: Ok. If you try my code above, what kind of error php trow?

Comment: It doesn't give an error but it also doesn't display anything.

Comment: I've tried to use urlencode() but it doesn't find the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_link = "http://graph.facebook.com/207640916063623/photos?fields=source";
```

You need token access:

```
$json_link = "http://graph.facebook.com/207640916063623/photos?fields=source&access_token=<token>";
```